# Cronjob not working on CentOS 6.5 Docker container

Tags: centos, docker, cron

I'm running cron on my CentOS6.5 Docker container and when I do `ps ef | grep cron` it shows up so I know it's running.

I have below command after going into `crontab -e`

```
* * * * * /bin/touch /tmp/env.output
```

This however silently fails and I cannot see any `/tmp/env.output`

Crontab is running as root aswell and I can touch env.output with same user so it does not seem to be permission issue.

Is there anywhere else I need to check?

Comment: check root's mail spool. cron usually emails job output/stats to the account under which the job ran.

Comment: @MarcB where do I go and check this?

Comment: @MarcB there's nothing under `/var/spool/mail/` no file in that directory

Comment: Also worth checking your syslog for cron errors - `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel nope there isn't any syslog file

Comment: Try changing to `* * * * * root /bin/touch /tmp/env.output`

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel nope no luck

Comment: can you share you Dockerfile especially parts where you setting cron and installing it (yum install .. )